Assigning a domain name to localhost for development environment without editing etc/hosts File
I am developing React applications on a Windows machine where I am not allowed to edit my /etc/hosts File.
Like many of the other posts through the years I want to change localhost:3000 to a different domain name.
For instance:
127.0.0.1 testdomain
Is there a work around that does not involve editing the hosts file on a Windows machine?
